# Erlang API for bigquery

Tags: erlang, google-bigquery, riak, google-compute-engine

Is there an Erlang API for bigquery?

I would like to use Bigquery from Google Compute Engine in a Linux instance.
I would like to run Riak NoSQL there.

Comment: I can only find these drivers https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no Erlang client for BigQuery. You can always generate the HTTP REST requests by hand -- it is relatively straightforward for most use-cases. Alternately, you could execute a shell command that runs the bq.py command line client.